# Possible to use Entity getters in custom repository?

Tags: symfony, repository, entity

I am in need of grabbing a few fields of an entity, running them through some processing, and returning the processed data. I am wondering if it is possible to call the getters of the Entity for which the custom repository is being built inside that custom repository? The only way I thought of so far seems like it would create an infinite loop by calling the entity's repository, which would include a call to the very custom repository being used as well.

I can write the actual queries, but I figured it it would be cleaner to access the data through existing methods, then why not?

---

Update: So I built a method in the custom repository that I pass the entity object to that I want to work with. Seems a little weird that I would have to pass the entity to it's own custom repository so that it would know what to act on, but I can't seem to find any other way. So in my Controller right now I am calling the entity, then calling up the repository for the entity, and passing the previously called entity to the repository. Is that right?

```
$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

$user_repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User');

$profiles = $user_repository->getAllUsersProfiles($user);
```

Comment: can you share the User schema? Maybe this can be done inside your own User class.

Comment: @StivenLlupa I can only find references to that for Symfony 1, such as http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/doctrine/1_2/en/04-schema-files. If that  is what you're referencing, it seems quite similar to the Symfony2 Entity/Repository classes I am already using. Correct me if that is not what you mean, please.

Comment: Ok, based on your code, a user has many profiles. Normally you should have two entities User and Profile and in the user class an association of oneToMany. If for some reason you need a custom method to filter these profiles based on some criteria, you can create a function inside User, going through each profile object and filter them, then return them. No need to pass $user on its own Repository.

Comment: I realised I was looking at this all wrong. I have now changed to placing any code that grabs a specific entity or set of entities, regardless of the parameters passed to it to filter by, in the Custom Repository for that entity being filtered.

So before I had a User Custom Repository with getUsersCampaigns($user) and getUsersProfiles($user), but those now reside in the Campaign and Profile Custom Repositories, respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had the whole concept of Custom Repositories incorrect. I was using them to store methods that would pull out data relevant to the entity, but only relevant in the sense that the entity was being used to filter something else.

Prior to this epiphany my User Custom Repository had methods like getAllUsersProfiles($user) and getAllUsersCampaigns($user). My previously incorrect understanding was that because the User entity was the thing that was central to filtering the Profiles and Campaigns, that these belonged in the User Custom Repository.

What I have now come to understand is that getAllUserProfiles($user) belongs in the Profiles Custom Repository, and would be more appropriately named getAllByUser($user). Now when I need to use it, I pull up the Profiles Repository and call the appropriate method:

```
$profile_repository  = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Profile');
$all_profiles = $profile_repository->getAllByUser($user);
```